# Regex satisfying multiple conditions

Tags: regex

First of all, I have found several examples relating to my query. But none of them was helpful.

Could you please help me to create a regex which satisfies following 3 conditions:

1. String must contain exactly one alphabetic character
2. String must contain digits
3. String must be 9 length

I believe following regex can be used to validate the 3rd condition:
`\A(?=\w{9,9}\z)`

But I was unable to figure out how to combine multiple conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
^(?=[^\r\na-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z][^\r\na-zA-Z]*)(?=.*[0-9].*).{9}$
```

Or, if you do not allow anything other than digits and letters:

```
^(?=[^\r\na-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z][^\r\na-zA-Z]*)(?=.*[0-9].*)[0-9a-zA-Z]{9}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zH6uA1/2).

Explanation:

- `^` - String start
- `(?=[^\r\na-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z][^\r\na-zA-Z]*)` - Ensure there is only 1 letter in the 9-character string
- `(?=.*[0-9].*)` - Ensure that there are digits
- `[0-9a-zA-Z]{9}` - The string is 9 characters long (only allowing numbers and characters)
  (or `.{9}` - will allow any characters)
- `$` - String end

Mind that `[^\r\n]` is added for a more reliable testing on regex101, if you test individual strings (not multiline lists), you can just use `^(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]*)(?=.*[0-9].*)[0-9a-zA-Z]{9}$`.

```js
function isValidPassword(str) {
   return /^(?=[^\r\na-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z][^\r\na-zA-Z]*$)(?=.*[0-9].*$)[0-9a-zA-Z]{9}$/.test(str);
}

document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = "3445345f3 is " + isValidPassword('3445345f3') + "<br>222222222 is " + isValidPassword("222222222");
```

```html
<div id="res"/>
```

Comment: There is no need to look to the end of the input in the look-ahead. `(?=.*[0-9])` is sufficient